# What would be the RegularExpression for the followings?

Tags: vb.net, regex, .net-2.0

I have a nomenclature to respect while performing some tasks against the Active Directory.

Here's the nomenclature:

> - **TT**-EEE-Mnemonic: if **TT** = 'GA' or 'GS' or 'PA' or 'PF' -> the schema to create is a "group", with a groupScope of *Global*.
>
>   2. **LT**-EEE-Mnemonic: if **T** = 'A' or 'G' or 'I' or 'N' or 'P' -> the schema to create is a "group", with a groupScope of *Domain local*.
>   3. **TTT**-EEE-Mnemonic: if **TTT*** = 'CNX' or 'GST' or 'SVC' -> the shema to create is an "user"
>   4. **T**-SSSS-Mnemonic: if **T** = 'A' or 'L' or 'M' or 'R' or 'S' -> the schema to create is an "organizationUnit"

What I'm after is a simpler and more effective way than this:

```
If(dn.Substring(3, 2).Contains("GA") _
    Or variable.Substring(3, 2).Contains("GS") _
    Or dn.Substring(3, 2).Contains("PA") _
    Or dn.Substring(3, 2).Contains("PF")) Then 
    schema = "group" ' Global'
Else If(dn.Substring(4, 1).Contains("A") _
    Or dn.Substring(4, 1).Contains("G") _
    Or dn.Substring(4, 1).Contains("I") _
    Or dn.Substring(4, 1).Contains("N") _
    Or dn.Substring(4, 1).Contains("P")) Then
    schema = "group" ' Local'
Else If(dn.Substring(3, 3).Contains("CNX") _
    ' Well... You get the idea, don't you?
End If
```

I guess I could use a `RegularExpression`, or perhaps one for each of the nomenclature I got, something alike.

Is there a way a `RegularExpression` could become handy in this situation? Or would it be best to stick with that old big-If? Any suggestions are welcome.

Sorry for asking, but I'm not used to use `RegularExpression`. I know they exist, and bit of what they can do, but that's all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd vastly reduce the number of tests and explicit `Or`s.

```
If Regex.IsMatch(dn, "^CN=(G[AS]|P[AF])-") Then
    schema = "group"    ' Global                 'damn syntax highlighting
ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(dn, "^CN=L[AGINP]-") Then
    schema = "group"    ' Local                  'damn syntax highlighting
ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(dn, "^CN=(CNX|GST|SVC)-") Then
    schema = "user"
ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(dn, "^CN=[ALMRS]-") Then
    schema = "organizationUnit"
End If
```

Comment: @cHao: Thanks! That seems to reflect the idea behind my question.

Comment: @cHao: What the ^ character means in RegEx?

Comment: @Will Marcouiller: It anchors the pattern to the start of the string.  Without it, the pattern will match (for example) "CN=GA-" anywhere in the string -- which might not be a bad thing, if for some reason you can't guarantee that what you're looking for is at the start.

Comment: In LDAP, the *distinguishedName* property always begins with the name of the object (CN), and from bottom-up with the OU's until the end of the domain name. I get your point though, but in my situation, I absolutely need it in the beginning of the string.

Comment: Then the ^ is appropriate.  :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the ^ character obliges the RegEx to match from the beginning of the string. The characters you want constant, you simply put them in. You put within square brackets the values that a certain position can have, and you separate each combination with a | character. What about the parentheses? (Am I right in my affirmation, I'm trying to learn meanwhile. =))

Comment: The square brackets will match any one of the characters inside them.  `[ALMRS]`, for example, matches either A, L, M, R, or S.  The `|` is pretty much like an "or", but it's rather odd prioritywise -- without parentheses, it can cut a regex right in two. If the parentheses weren't there, it'd the first pattern would match "CN=GA some garbage" or "some garbage PF-more garbage" etc, because the ^ is part of the first alternative, not the whole expression.  You need to use some kind of grouping to fix that.

Comment: Parentheses can also tell a regex to capture the part that'd be inside them, and return it as a string.  But if you're just looking for matches, they don't do much except group stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not seem to conform your description. With your description, you may want the following regular expression:

```
^(((GA|GS|PA|PF)|L[AGINP]|(CNX|GST|SVC))-EEE|[ALRMS]-SSSS)$
```

EDIT: you may want to read up [this tutorial](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html) about what the regular expression means, specifically look for the "Character classes" and "Grouping and alternatives" sections.

In short, the bar character (i.e. |) is the "OR" operator. The square brackets (i.e. []) are the character class; in other words, "OR" between the characters.

Comment: LOL! (too much characters are required here...)

Comment: @William: I may recognize the characters I'm after, and even come to a little understanding of the `RegEx` suggested. Might you explain it just a little bit more so that I don't need to come and bother SO because I can't write one alone as I'm not used to it? Thanks for your help! =)

Comment: From this, how can I differentiate whether it's a "user", an "organizationalUnit", a "group" (local) or a "group" (global) clearly, so that I may pass the obtained schema based on the `RegEx` to pass to my Create() method? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @William: Thanks for your explanation, and double thanks for the tutorial link. =)

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
Dim Schema As String = Nothing
Select Case dn.SubString(3, 2) ' Am not sure about your index of 3 here!
  Case "GA", "GS", "PA", "PS"
    Schema = "group"
End Select

If IsNothing(Schema) Then
  Select Case ...
End If

etc.
```

Comment: ...admittedly not regex but then why bother when a simple solution exists?

Comment: The index of 3 is because I got the distinguishedName value of the object to create into the underlying directory. Its form is: "CN=TT-EEE-Mnemonic,OU=lowerOU,OU=middleOU,OU=highestOU,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com". In order to get the `TT`, I need to access index 3. =)

Comment: Even though not a `RegEx`, this is a simple solution, and simpler for a colleague who who have to debug my code. I agree, I don't bother much if the best solution isn't `RegEx`, I just thought it would be simpler with it. =)